# Fancy box Doesn't open a page in fancybox popup when using IE

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I am using `fancybox` as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('[id*=addnewRequest]').fancybox({
                'width': 760,
                'height': 540,
                'padding': 0,
                'margin': 0,
                'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
                'scrolling': 'auto',
                'autoScale': false,
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'type': 'iframe',
                'centerOnScroll': true,
                'onClosed': function () {

                }
            });
        });
```

it is working fine with all browser except `IE`. Any Idea ?

Comment: Can you provide a JS fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your code :

```
$('[id*=addnewRequest]').fancybox( ...
```

.... makes me think that you are repeating the same `ID` for several elements in the same document, aren't you?

In this case IE is less tolerant than other browsers and it won't work for such selectors with the same `ID` but the first. This is documented here http://fancybox.net/faq, No.7.

`ID`s should be unique, which it means that only one element should have the same `ID` within the same document.... you should use *classes* so instead of this :

```
<a id="addnewRequest" href="{first target}"...
<a id="addnewRequest" href="{second target}"...
```

... and

```
$('[id*=addnewRequest]').fancybox( ...
```

You should have :

```
<a class="addnewRequest" href="{first target}"...
<a class="addnewRequest" href="{second target}"...
```

... and

```
$('.addnewRequest').fancybox( ...
```